# jruby does not understand import statement

Tags: jruby, jruby-java-interop

I'm converting a project written with JRuby 1.7 in mind to JRuby 9.4. One of the files starts like this:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'

  require 'java'
  import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

  ....

end
```

The `import` does not work anymore. With JRuby 9.4, just compiling this file produces the error message *NoMethodError: undefined method `import' for main:Object*.

My understanding was that `require 'java'` would provide the `import` method, and at least it was working with JRuby 1.7.

In case it matters: We are using the imported class like this:

```
current_heap_in_bytes = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage.used
```

Comment: On a tangent, I would strongly recommend either sticking to the 9.3 branch or waiting for JRuby 9.4.1.0 before upgrading. The 9.x.0.0 versions of JRuby are a bit notorious for having bugs, and I know there's at least one fairly serious JIT bug  in 9.4.0.0 (causing some method calls to crash or misbehave once your code has been running long enough) that [has been fixed in master](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/commit/129bd6312839fed1e7054af22607bbcd09b8ec21) but not in any released version yet.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen : Thank you for pointing this out. I'm now doing just the first experiments with the new version. For switching from 1.7 to 9.x, I will for sure wait first for 9.4.1.0 to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this page:

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#from-class-files

There is mention of the `java_import` method. Does that help?

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. In particular, running the OP's code in verbose mode on JRuby 9.3.9.0, I get a warning saying "import is deprecated; use java_import". Presumably the deprecated ability to use `import` instead of `java_import` was removed in JRuby 9.4.